# Package not working when deployed as Job in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

I have developed an ssis package where I am storing the result in an excel sheet in path

```
E:\output\report\Account_28 Mar 2012.xls
```

Now again I open the file from the above path write few contents to it in specified cells and I am saving it back. This works fine if in my solution vs 2008 I have deployed this package in server it self, no issues at all if I run in my solution. Everything works fine

But if I take my package and configuration from the solution and deployed in the server as a job  and  run it it gives me this error

> Microsoft Excel cannot access the file
>   E:\output\report\ExpiredAccount_28 Mar 2012.xls . There are several
>   possible reasons:    ?  The file name or path does not exist.  ? The
>   file is being used by another program.  ? The workbook you are trying
>   to save has the same name as  a currently open workbook.

**I don't understand why it fails when I run as job here ?**

Environment: SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio 2008, SQL Server 2005, Windows server 2008

Error

> :You may not be authorized to access this information. This error
>   occurs when there is a cryptographic error.  Verify that the correct
>   key is available.  End Error  Error: 2012-03-28 10:39:45.49     Code:
>   0x00000001      Source: Update the contents of  file      Description:
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:  Exception has been
>   thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC):  Microsoft
>   Excel cannot access the file 'E:\output\report\Account_28 Mar 2012.xls
>   Mar 2012.xls'. There are several possible reasons:    ?  The file name
>   or path does not exist.  ? The file is being used by another program. 
>   ? The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as  a
>   currently open workbook.     at
>   ST_889a4dfd8e9647039213f39fd4c966ab.csproj.ScriptMain.Main()     ---
>   End of inner exception stack trace ---      at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes,
>   RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)     at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig,   MethodAttributes methodAttributes,
>   RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)     at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture,
>   Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)       at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags
>   bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs,
>   ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[]
>   namedParams)       at System.Type.InvokeMember(String name,
>   BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] args,
>   CultureInfo culture)       at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()
>   End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).
>   Started:  10:39:34  Finished: 10:39:45  Elapsed:  10.53 seconds.  The
>   package execution failed.  The step failed.

Please see the code I am using for opening an Excel file and saving it back

```
public void Main()
{
    try
    {
        string StartDate = string.Empty;
        string EndDate = string.Empty;
        string Reportname = "Employee list"
        string Countryname = "India"
        string Filename = Dts.Variables["User::FileName"].Value.ToString() + ".xls";
        string CurrentDate = Dts.Variables["User::CurrentDate"].Value.ToString();
        string strStarDate = Dts.Variables["User::StartDateTime"].Value.ToString();
        string strEndDate = Dts.Variables["User::EndDateTime"].Value.ToString();

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open(Filename, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

        Worksheet sheet = (Worksheet)wb.Sheets["Accounts"];
        Range excelRange = sheet.UsedRange;
        Range rng1 = sheet.get_Range("B1", "C1");
        sheet.get_Range("$B1", "$C1").HorizontalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft;
        sheet.get_Range(rng1.Cells[1, 1], rng1.Cells[1, 2]).Merge(Type.Missing);
        rng1.Value2 = Countryname;

        Range rng2 = sheet.get_Range("B2", "B2");
        sheet.get_Range("$B2", "$C2").HorizontalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft;

        sheet.get_Range(rng2.Cells[1, 1], rng2.Cells[1, 2]).Merge(Type.Missing);
        rng2.Value2 = Reportname;
        sheet.get_Range("B1", "B1").Font.Bold = true;
        sheet.get_Range("B1", "B1").Font.Size = 14;
        sheet.get_Range("B2", "B2").Font.Bold = true;
        sheet.get_Range("B2", "B2").Font.Size = 14;
        Range rng3 = sheet.get_Range("A3", "A3");
        sheet.get_Range("$A3", "$B3").HorizontalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft;
        sheet.get_Range(rng3.Cells[1, 1], rng3.Cells[1, 2]).Merge(Type.Missing);
        rng3.Value2 = "TimeFrame  : " + strStarDate + " " + strEndDate;
        Range rng5 = sheet.get_Range("C3", "C3");
        rng5.Value2 = "Report Run Date : " + "  " + CurrentDate; ;
        sheet.get_Range("A4", "A4").Font.Bold = true;
        sheet.get_Range("A4", "A4").Font.Size = 11;
        //  sheet.get_Range("B3", "B3").ColumnWidth = 56;
        sheet.get_Range("A4", "A4").Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
        //Color.Violet.ToArgb(); 

        sheet.get_Range("B4", "B4").Font.Bold = true;
        sheet.get_Range("B4", "B4").Font.Size = 11;
        sheet.get_Range("B4", "B4").Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);

        sheet.get_Range("C4", "C4").Font.Bold = true;
        sheet.get_Range("C4", "C4").Font.Size = 11;
        sheet.get_Range("C4", "C4").Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);

        sheet.get_Range("D4", "D4").Font.Bold = true;
        sheet.get_Range("D4", "D4").Font.Size = 11;
        sheet.get_Range("D4", "D4").Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);

        wb.RefreshAll();
        wb.Save();
        app.Workbooks.Close();
        app.Quit();
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is Excel installed on that server you're trying to run this on?? Does that server have a drive/directory `E:\output\report` ?? Does the user running this package have permissions on that directory (if it exists)??

Comment: please find the answer above how i solved it permissions issue to access the excel

Answer (score 1):

(Answered by the OP in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> how I solved it
>
> Under `component services > Computers > My Computer > DCOM Config + Microsoft Excel application > properties > Identity Tab > Select the Interactive User > Ok`.
>
> then in the code I made this change to explicitly close the file which was opened `app.Workbooks.Close();`